# Datepicker in form doesn't work in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I have installed

---

> -windows server 2012 R2  in french language
>
> -sql server 2016 in english language
>
> -sharepoint 2016 in french language
>
> -infopath 2013 in french language

I've created my form and I published it in SharePoint. Now the problem is that the datepicker is not displayed. I got the following in my console

`datetime1036 is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some articles speaking about this, it seems this would be no root site created for that particular web application.

Make sure you have created a root site collection for the web application.

Best Regards,

Lisa Chen